# cf.exe: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: ibm-cloud

I have been trying to install IBM bluemix CLI and getting this error message while trying to push my php file to the server:

C:\xampp\htdocs\bluemix>bluemix app push index
Invoking 'cf push index'...

FAILED
fork/exec C:\Program Files\IBM\Bluemix\bin\cfcli\cf.exe: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

C:\xampp\htdocs\bluemix>

I cannot understand understand.  I am using Windows 10 - 64 bit system.  I have been trying to install bluemix both 64 and 32 bit and none works.  I wonder what else is lacking.  Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Here is the link with the right version. After I installed it worked.

https://console.bluemix.net/docs/cli/reference/bluemix_cli/get_started.html#getting-started